# Use fewer if statements to test in which interval a given integer belongs

Tags: python

```
m = int(input("How many marks on the test? (/100)"))
if m >= 10 and m < 20:
    print("Grade 1.")
elif m >= 20 and m < 30:
    print("Grade 2.")
elif m >= 30 and m < 40:
    print("Grade 3.")
```

The code above is for grading a test score out of 100, with grades 1 to 9, 9 being the highest at 90 or higher marks.

How could I do the same code but with less if/elif statements?

Comment: `print(f'Grade {m // 10}.')`

Comment: Not directly answering your question (@Yevhen did very well) but in cases where you have no formula to avoid the conditionals, you can make them more pythonic by using a single condition instead of two:  `if m>=10 and m<20:`  can be converted to `if 10 <= m < 20:`

Comment: @mkrieger1 that will only work if the first condition doesn;t have a lower boundary. However in this case it does, so this makes the second condition accept values between 20 and 30 but also values in the range (-inf, 10)  which is an undesired behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the grades are evenly spaced and directly proportional to the score, you can just do an integer division, `a//b`.

But if the scale isn’t linear, I suggest doing it by looping through a list of thresholds:

```py
grades = [
    30, # 1 (lowest passing grade)
    50, # 2
    60, # 3
    70, # 4
    75, # 5
    # more grades...
]

score = int(input("score"))

for grade, threshold in enumerate(grades):
    if score < threshold:
        print(f"grade: {grade}")
        break
else:
    # this happens if the score is
    # higher than the highest grade
    # threshold in the list (75 in
    # this case)
    print("Wow, very high score!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yevhen's solution is undoubtedly the best for this particular scenario with uniform boundary sizes. Although it does get 100/100 wrong (grade 10) if the upper limit is supposed to be grade 9.

If things were a little different (i.e. grade 3 spanned from 30 to 50) then you could look at an approach like below:

```
m = int(input("How many marks on the test? (/100)"))

grades = {0: {"lb": 0, "ub":10},
          1: {"lb": 10, "ub":20},
          2: {"lb": 20, "ub":30}, 
          3: {"lb": 30, "ub": 40},
          4: {"lb": 40, "ub": 50},
          5: {"lb": 50, "ub": 60},
          6: {"lb": 60, "ub": 70},
          7: {"lb": 70, "ub": 80},
          8: {"lb": 80, "ub": 90},
          9: {"lb": 90, "ub": 101},
          }

for grade, bounds in grades.items():
    if m >= bounds["lb"] and m < bounds["ub"]:
        print(f"Grade {grade}")
        break
```

In this instance, the dictionary as above could be auto-generated by:

```
grades = {}
for grade in range(0, 10):
    grades[grade] = {"lb": grade*10, "ub": (grade+1)*10}
grades[9]["ub"] = 101  # The correction to avoid grade 10 if mark is 100
```

edit: Should probably also point out the handy thing about this is you can name the main key whatever you want, grades A*, A, B+, B, B- etc? No problem.

For more complex use cases, you could even tack on additional key-val pairs to different things, even different method handles, for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way;

```
m = 56
# gradeDict = {'score':'grade'}
gradeDict = {10:1,
             20:2,
             30:3,
             40:4,
             50:5,
             60:6,
             70:7,
             80:8,
             90:9,
             100:9}


for k in gradeDict.items():
    if m<k[0]:
        print("score:", k[1]-1)
        break
```

This is the output;

```
score: 5
```

Comment: Instead `for k in ...` you can write `for score, grade in ...`, then the comment above is not needed and you can replace `k[0]` by `score` and `k[1]` by `grade`. Also, why subtract 1 from the score instead of just putting the correct values into `gradeDict`?

Comment: I know I can write ```score``` and ```grade```, but my solution does two things, first it grabs a tuple, second it does not need an else statement if the value ```m``` is larger than``` k```. The ```-1``` is there for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use this nice property of range? One can actually check what's in it. If you have two zipped lists of ranges and grades, or two lists of tuples, you can check if the value is in one element of a tuple and return the other one.

```
points = 25
ranges = [range(10, 20), range(20, 30), range(30, 40), range(90, 101)]
grades = [1, 2, 3, 10]
zipped = zip(ranges, grades)
for item in zipped:
    if points in item[0]:
        result = f'Grade {item[1]}.'
        break
print(result)
```